# How can I match two columns using boolean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a condition that checks in a dataframe if each row in two columns have data in them, and if so to enter a value into another column. I get a ValueError ambigious. I think this might be a weird way to do it, but I also want to create input conditions where column a is True and column B is False and vice-verse.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['y', '','z'], 'b': ['x','', '']})


if df['a'].notna() == True & df['b'].notna() == True:
    df['match'] = 'MATCH'

if df['a'].notna() == False & df['b'].notna() == False:
    df['match'] = 'NO_MATCH'
```

Out:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: perhaps series equal ? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html#pandas.Series.eq . In your example row-wise comparison but actually comparing two series. apply(lambda x: ....) will do row-wise comparison

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is based on whether or not there's an empty string. You're hitting an order of operations problem, note this doesn't give you an error:

```
>>> (df['a'].notna() == True) & (df['b'].notna() == True)
```

But you can do this much more simply:

```
>>> df.loc[~df['a'].eq('') & ~df['b'].eq(''),'match'] = 'MATCH'
>>> df['match'] = df['match'].fillna('NO_MATCH')
>>> df
   a  b     match
0  y  x     MATCH
1        NO_MATCH
2  z     NO_MATCH
```

I recommend you read up on De Morgan's laws to understand why the two conditions you listed aren't mutually comprehensive. The complement of the union of the true conditions is the disjunction of the false conditions:

```
(df['a'].notna() == False) | (df['b'].notna() == False)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `numpy.where` with `pandas.DataFrame.all`:

```
df["match"] = np.where(df.all(1), "Match", "No_match")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   a  b     match
0  y  x     Match
1        No_match
2  z     No_match
```